# Counting number of objects inside a collection of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a collection of arrays each with a dynamic number of objects inside them:

```
arr1=[obj1, obj2, obj3, other1, other2]
arr2=[obj1, obj2, other1]
...
```

I want to count the number of objects in total, ignoring the "others" and only counting "obj" objects.

I'm not sure if i can achieve this with array destructuring, or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you interested in building your own slideshow? there are tons of react slideshow libraries that exist already https://github.com/femioladeji/react-slideshow looks pretty good but there are literally hundreds of choices. you can look at the source to see how they're doing it

Comment: I prefer to make my custom slideshow though

Comment: Why are you using functions like 'querySelector' instead of using `ref` ?

Comment: you shouldn't even need `ref` for this. just apply the correct styles using `style={}` or `className`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide a cleanup function (returned from useEffect) that can clear the timeouts when the component is removed from the DOM.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect

Edit: I see in the update that you used clearTimeout, but you haven’t provided that example so hard to say why it didn’t work for you. Cleanup is the way to solve the problem you described.

Technically you could create this slideshow with a single interval, but it would also need cleanup.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, the problem is that when the component unmounts from the dom, these 3 setTimeouts are still running and searching for the element who's class is `.side h1`, etc.

`useEffect` can do cleanups when the component unmounts: [read this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

So to fix this problem:

```
let timeOuts = [];
useEffect(() => {
    timeOuts[0] = setTimeout(() => { document.querySelector('.slide1 h1').style.cssText += 'opacity:1;left:0' },3000) 
    timeOuts[1] = ssetTimeout(() => { document.querySelector('.slide1 h2').style.cssText += 'opacity:1;left:0' },3500) 
    timeOuts[2] = ssetTimeout(() => { document.querySelector('.slide1 h3').style.cssText += 'opacity:1;left:0' },4000) 
}

return ()=>{
  //This is where the cleanup is put, because this gets called when the component unmounts
  timeOuts.foreach ((t)=>{
    clearTimeout (t);
  });
}
,[])
```

**But `useEffect` can do much more and can easily lead to problems If not understood well, so It is beter to read the documentation mentioned above on `useEffect`**

Comment: you haven't provided anything that i didn't mention already. Everything you wrote i already considered in my post - read it i wrote those things already and that they didn't work.

Comment: basically i did exactly that and i still get the error.

Comment: Here does the code you provided get executed ? In which component ? It should not execute in the parent, rather It should be placed in the component that is getting removed. So when routing check that the removed component is the one containing the timeouts

Comment: Try doing`console.log("something")` in the cleanup. If you see "something" in the console when the component is removed, then the previous comment is irrelevent